# Is there a way to update some items in RecyclerView without rebinding?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Let's say I have 40 items in a RecyclerView. 20 items in it all hold the same intent each that will be launched when touched. At every 5-second interval, the intent changes, so 20 of the 40 items will have their intents replaced

Is there a way to update all of the intents each of the 20 items hold without rebinding them?

Each time it rebinds the item disappears and appears, and at a 5-second time interval it wouldn't be visually pleasing to have items constantly appearing and disappearing.

I was thinking that the variable should all point to an object, so that when that object gets updated, the items' intent also gets updated. But Java is pass-by-value so no chance there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the visuals don't change, then there's no reason to rebind.  Just give the data to the items that need updating and don't call `RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged()` on the Adapter.  The `RecyclerView` won't be notified of a rebind and the underlying data will be updated.

If the visuals *do* change, but you don't want the flashing, then you can use a custom `ItemAnimator` that simply doesn't animate.

An even simpler method may be to simply call [ItemAnimator#setChangeDuration()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html#setChangeDuration(long)) with a value of 0 on the ItemAnimator you're using so it starts and finishes immediately.

Comment: Updating data WITHOUT notifying the adapter that the data has been changed will not have any effect whatsoever. Only when the adapter has been notified will the new value be replaced with the old value. In my case, I need no visual changes but data was not updated unless I call tell the adapter e.g. `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @Kyle. There are many reasons this might happen. I assume the adapter is backed by some kind of underlying data structure like a `List`. I also assume every time `onBind()` is called, you pass the item at position `x` have give it to a `ViewHolder`. You can update the item at position `x` without notifying the Adapter.  It would be updated in both the `List` and the `ViewHolder` because both objects contain references to the same item. The exception would be if you are caching or copying the item in which case you'll have two references created.

Comment: You're right - my adapter is backed with a data structure. If it weren't, then what you mentioned will probably work. Nevertheless, messing around with the ItemAnimator got me what I wanted - thanks for the excellent suggestion.